# JavaFx Dialog or Alert not displaying as expected on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, javafx, javafx-2

With reference to my this question, [fxml file not behaving as expected in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108836/fxml-file-not-behaving-as-expected-in-os-x), I am able to solve the first problem, but I am still facing the issue with my progress bar. It behaves fine when my app window is not maximized but when my app window is maximized my progress bar dialogue occupy the whole screen. My code for progress bar is this:

```
public ProgressBar startProgressBar() {
        primaryStage = new Stage();
        ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0);
        //ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(0);
        //pi.progressProperty().bind(pb.progressProperty());
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setSpacing(5);
        hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb.getChildren().addAll(pb);
        Scene scene = new Scene(hb, 300, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Downloading Build...");
        primaryStage.show();
        return pb;
    }
```

I have tried using the following but these doesn't work.

```
primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
primaryStage.setMaxHeight(200);
primaryStage.setMaxWidth(400);
```

but this also doesn't work. If I fix my height and width to constant the dialogue box take that height and width only but the background screen appears black.

I am triggering the progress bar once the user click on the download button this is my download process code. In progress bar, I am comparing my download file size and the size of the file from the server, I am updating the progress bar with the size of the file from my local directory.

```
private void download() {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPConnection().makeConnection(loc);

        try {
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            success = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(PATH + preset + "/" + file_to_download + offset);
            System.out.println("Download Path:-" + PATH + preset + "/" + file_to_download + offset);
            if (!success) {
                System.out.println("Could not changed the directory to RIBS");
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Directory changed to RIBS");
            }
            FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles();
            for (FTPFile file : files) {
                if (file.getName().contains(".zip")) {
                    dfile = file;
                }

            }
            fileMap.put("build", dfile.getName());
            //primaryStage = (Stage) ap.getScene().getWindow();

            String homePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
                        File downloadPath;
                        if(getOS().equals("Mac"))
                        {
                           downloadPath = new File(homePath + "/file path/" + osVer);
                        }
                        else
                        {
            downloadPath = new File(homePath + "\\file path\\" + osVer);
                        }
                        if (!downloadPath.exists()) {
                if (downloadPath.mkdirs()) {
                    System.out.println("Directory is created!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
                }
            }
            // System.out.println(chosenDir.getAbsolutePath());
            filePath = new File(downloadPath + "/" + dfile.getName());
            if (filePath.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File altready exist");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File already exists", "InfoBox: " + "",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                return;
            } else {

                downloadFile = new File(downloadPath + "/" + dfile.getName());
                // Progress bar
                Task<Void> progress = new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        try {
                            for (long progress = 0; progress < dfile.getSize() ; progress = downloadFile.length()) {
                                Thread.sleep(300);
                                System.out.println(progress);
                                updateProgress(progress, dfile.getSize());

                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                        finally {

                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                ProgressBar slider = startProgressBar();
                slider.progressProperty().bind(progress.progressProperty());

                // download task
                Task downloadTask = new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() throws IOException {
                        try {
                            long len = dfile.getSize();
                            System.out.println("File From Server:::::: " + len);

                            System.out.println("DOWNLOAD FILE:::::" + downloadFile);
                            outputFile = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        ftpClient.sendNoOp();
                        ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(1000);
                        // ftpClient.retrieveFile(dfile, output);
                        if (ftpClient.retrieveFile(dfile.getName(), outputFile) == true) {
                            System.out.println("ReplyCOde:-" + ftpClient.getReplyCode());
                            downloadButton.setDisable(true);

                            try {
                                String homePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
                                Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(homePath + "/file path"));
                                //primaryStage.hide();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println("LOCAL FILE LENGTH:-" + downloadFile.length());
                            if (outputFile != null) {
                                try {
                                    outputFile.close();
                                    ftpClient.logout();
                                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                Thread t = new Thread(downloadTask);
                t.start();

                Thread thread = new Thread(progress);
                thread.start();
                downloadTask.setOnSucceeded(evt->primaryStage.hide());

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //primaryStage.hide();
        }
        return;
    }
```

Any dialogue box have the similar behavior for Mac OS X. I tried JavaFx alert box also it also have the same behavior. Is there any work around?

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText("cannot connec to server or file not present at server");
```

Comment: A [mcve] would allow a Mac user to test your approach.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

The effect described is a feature of a dialog that has no owner. To suppress the unwanted behavior, specify an owner for the dialog in the example below:

```
alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
```

The [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) below may be used to reproduce the effect described on Mac OS X 10.11, El Capitan. After clicking on the green full-screen button in the top-left corner of the window, the application expands to fill the screen. Clicking the <kbd>Show Alert</kbd> button causes the expanded window to slide aside, disappearing to reveal the alert. Uncomment the call to `initOwner()` and retest. The expanded window (blue) now remains beneath the alert

No owner:

[image: now owner]

Owner set:

[image: owner set]

Apple [suggests](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18744?locale=en_US) either of two related workarounds:

- <kbd>Option</kbd>-click the green full-screen button in the top-left corner of an application window to expand in the manner of previous versions.
- Double-click the title bar, after selecting "Double-click a window's title bar to zoom" in the Dock preference pane.

Code:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37183801/230513
 */
public class AlertTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Show Alert");
        button.setOnAction(ae -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Are you sure?");
            alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                System.out.println("Confirmed!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Cancelled.");
            }
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane(button);
        root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
            Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Alert Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any work around for this problem if user clicks the green expand button ?

Comment: The problem goes away if you specify an owner for the alert; I've tried to clarify above.