# JavaFX is not maximized after alert

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, window

I try to program a little board game in Java with JavaFX, but I have a problem. When the Window is maximized and I switch scenes via an alert (on clicking "ok" in the alert the scene is going to switch), the Window becomes unmaximized, but the method isMaximized() still returns true. Set the window unmaximized and then maximized again via code does not work. If the user maximizes the window again, it works. Any ideas how I can fix this problem?

```
//Original
public void onLeave(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if(leaveAlert()) {
        GUI.INSTANCE.setPane(MenuPane.PANE);
        // stage.isMaximized() == true here, but window is not maximized
    }
}

//First try to fix it, but does not work too
public void onLeave(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if(leaveAlert()) {
        GUI.getStage().setMaximized(false);
        GUI.INSTANCE.setPane(MenuPane.PANE);
        GUI.getStage().setMaximized(true);
    }
}

private boolean leaveAlert() {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Leave");
    alert.setHeaderText("You are about to leave.");
    alert.setContentText("Are you sure you want to leave?");

    return alert.showAndWait().get() == ButtonType.OK;
}

// in class GUI
public void setPane(Pane pane) {
    stage.getScene().setRoot(pane);
    stage.show();
}
```

(Sorry for my poor English skills)

Comment: `initOwner()`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37183801/230513)?

Comment: How I have to use this? GUI.getStage() is my primary stage and my only stage.

Comment: I can't tell from your fragment. Why not try the example and see what happens on your platform?