# why JOptionPane.showMessageDialog just working in main?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using NetBeans last version and macOS. I try this is my code and  `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` not working. It's working if I put the syntax in the main. Please tell me why. I try [vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode), and I have same problem

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    TextField txt;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label lb1 = new Label();
        TextField txt = new TextField("Type here");
        RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();
        RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();
        Button bt = new Button("click");
        Button bt1 = new Button("anas aljaghbeer");
        MyHandlerClass handler1 = new MyHandlerClass();

        bt.setOnAction(handler1);
        txt.setPrefSize(10, 10);
        lb1.setText("Enter here");
        txt.getText();

        VBox box = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 1000, 1000);

        box.getChildren().addAll(lb1, txt, bt);
        primaryStage.setTitle("anas");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class MyHandlerClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Hello");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn’t work because you don’t import it, BUT, don’t use `JOptionPane`, JavaFX has [dialogs](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/).

Comment: Don't mix Swing and JavaFX. If you do, you have to manage two different UI threads.

Comment: The Swing import was lurking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/aebc48c3-a13b-44cb-b239-74f26db14bab/view-source), behind the code fence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`…It's working if I put the syntax in the main. Please tell me why.

When you invoke `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` in `main()`, it executes on the [*initial thread*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). In a *Swing* program, you would invoke it from `main()` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Click to continue…");
        …
    });
}
```

In a *JavaFX* program you are [well advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70517898/why-joptionpane-showmessagedialog-just-working-in-main#comment124659049_70517898) *not* to "mix Swing and JavaFX," unless you account for [*JavaFX-Swing Interoperability*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_swing.htm). Instead, evoke an `Alert` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37183801/230513) and below:

[image: Alert image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    TextField txt;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label();
        TextField text = new TextField("Type here");
        Button button = new Button("Click");
        MyHandlerClass handler = new MyHandlerClass();

        button.setOnAction(handler);
        text.setPrefSize(10, 10);
        label.setText("Enter here");
        text.getText();

        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().addAll(label, text, button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 320, 240);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("anas");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class MyHandlerClass implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "You clicked the button.");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```