JavaFX minimizable dialog across operating systems
I want a non-modal Dialog that can be minimized (the OS shows a minimize button at the top of the window) on every OS. The only way I've found to do this on windows is for the dialog not to have an owner. However, when I have used dialogs without owners, mac users have told me when the primary stage is maximized the dialogs take up the full screen with black all around them, as is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37183801/230513. Edit: Thanks to commenters I see that this is only for some mac users.
From what mac users have told me, neither the dialogs with or without owners are minimizable dialogs with owners aren't minimizable. So I've yet to find a way to make dialogs minimizable on macs without causing the bug for some mac users. I haven't tested any Linux distros either since not many of my users use them. Ideally I would like a single way to make a dialog minimizable irregardless of the OS but if necessary I could use different methods for different OS's, or even different versions of macOS.
Here's an example where no owner is set so it's minimizable on Windows, but apparently causes the bug for some mac users:
public class DialogTest extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Show Alert");
        button.setOnAction(ae -> {
            Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
            dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
            dialog.initModality(Modality.NONE);
            // dialog.initOwner(primaryStage);
            dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
            dialog.showAndWait();
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Dialog Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}


Since it seems that Dialog is not a good fit for your case, have you tried to create your own using a Stage?

No, although it occurred to me this should work. But in my actual application I have a certain type of dialog that is often used, and only sometimes do I want it to be minimizable. But if I make the minimizable one not a Dialog that may cause inconsistencies and repeated code.

I tested  this on a Mac and could minimize the dialog. I agree with @SedJ601 though, just implement this with a Stage. If it results in repetitive code, just use normal programming techniques to remove the repetitiion.

@James_D If you don't call initStyle is it still minimizable? Maybe that's what I was missing before. I would rather not use a Stage as I'd also have to re-invent some of the existing dialog behaviour, for example converting button types to actual buttons and returning a result based on which button was pressed (or whether the dialog was closed). And it will be hard to replicate the look of the Dialogs exactly for consistency with them. Why is it not possible to just minimize a Dialog when it is with a Stage?

"If you don't call initStyle is it still minimizable?" Yes, in quick testing.

Could you not test the platform and then write platform specific code to do what you want on that platform?

@jewelsea Yes, I mentioned I was open to that, but currently I don't know how to make the minimization work on a mac. Although it works for James_D, perhaps due to a different version of the OS.

On Mac OS, like @James_D, I am able to minimize the dialog, but the effect is to minimize and close the dialog; when the stage is maximized and the dialog is evoked, I see the effect cited.
